# Accessing GPU in Docker for Pytorch Model

Tags: docker, pytorch, dockerfile

I developed a machine learning model and integrated it with Flask app.When I try to run the docker image for the app, it says I do not have a GPU access. How should I write a Dockerfile such that I can use "cuda gpu" inside the container ? Below is the current state of Dockerfile.

FROM  python:3.9

WORKDIR /myapp

ADD . /myapp

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python","./app.py" ]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `--gpus` argument when executing `docker run`, check out the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Comment: Hi, should I run it as follows ? docker container run --gpus all myapp

Comment: Yes this is one option - but I recommend trying it.

Comment: I was reading through the document; however there is still a point I did not get.  It only uses apt-get to install nvidia container runtime in documentation. Is it not possible to use cuda gpu without using "FROM ubuntu " in dockerfile.

Comment: That's a completely separate question, but I think you do need to define *some* operating system.